# Why is the electric current is a scalar quantity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinetic-theory

Please help me because I didn't know **why**.
If you know please help me!!

Comment: A scalar is invariant under rotations, is current?

Comment: Yes it is under rotations.

Comment: What about its sign under a 180 deg rotation?